# Interface for connecting printer

Tags: ios, swift

How to develop an interface for connecting to receipt printer (IP based) available in network for iPad applications in Swift, are there any frameworks available?

Comment: Apple has AirPrint (https://developer.apple.com/airprint/) don't know if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: No my printer model is Epson TM-U220B its not wifi enabled,and i need to create interface which connects all TM based printer models which uses ethernet port and gets connected by using ipaddress

Comment: hmm, not something I've ever dabbled in so I don't have anything intelligent to say, sorry...and good luck :)

Comment: @PraveenJain have you found a solution to your problem? I have the same issue and haven't found a good solution yet..